# How to get string from 'window.getSelection' and how to fix opening new tab by using 'window.open'?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am creating the extension for Firefox (I use ver.65) which suppose to search a movie's title on Filmweb website (an equivalent of IMDB). It would happen by using the selection on any website and combine with Filmweb's search side address, and then go to that address on a new tab.

I tried to use **document.getSelection** instead of **window.getSelection** but it didn't work.

**filmwebExt.js**

```
const contextMenuItem = {
    id: "search-on-Filmweb",
    title: "Search on Filmweb",
    contexts: ["selection"]
};

function getSelectionText() {
    console.log('window.getSelection: ',window.getSelection());
    var text = "true";
    if (window.getSelection()) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
        console.log(text); //empty in debbuging console
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    console.log(text); //empty in debbuging console
    return text;
}
console.log('second window.getSelection: ',window.getSelection());
browser.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);
browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info) {

    const selectedText = getSelectionText();
    const url = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/search?q=';
    const fullUrlAddress = url + selectedText;
    if (info.menuItemId === "search-on-Filmweb") {
        console.log('comparison: ',info.menuItemId === "search-on-Filmweb");
        console.log("selectedText ",selectedText," fullUrlAddress ",fullUrlAddress);
        window.open(fullUrlAddress, '_blank');
    }
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Filmweb_Search",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Adds Filmweb search option in context menu",
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "wisznu@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "filmwebExt.js"
    ]
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/Filmweb_icon48x48.png",
    "96": "icons/Filmweb_icon96x96.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "filmwebExt.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "contextMenus"
  ]
}
```

Currently, the context menu item shows in the context menu properly, but the debugging console shows that **window.getSelection()** returns null values in an object and empty string for **window.getSelection().toString()**

[image: a debugging console log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the infrastructure of Firefox Add-On is still similar to what it was years ago, the problem here is that you cannot access from the process where the context menu is, to the selection of the document.

I believe that is for this very reason that the `info` object was added, so that you can have the information you need in the process where your code is running.
The object `info` has a property called `selectionText`, and that's what you have to use.

And for opening a new tab, it's better if you use the tabs API.

So, to summarize, your **filmwebExt.js**'s file would looks like:

```
const contextMenuItem = {
  id: "search-on-Filmweb",
  title: "Search on Filmweb",
  contexts: ["selection"]
};

browser.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);
browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(info => {
  if (info.menuItemId === "search-on-Filmweb") {
    const url = "https://www.filmweb.pl/search?q=" + info.selectionText;

    browser.tabs.create({ url });
});
```